# database and front end not fetching data

Tags: php

This is my code for insert data from form.
        i can add data directly from database but when i used to insert data by html form i didnt get any error . it goes to resume uploaded
    successfully. but can see any data add in front end and also in
    database.

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        include('db.php');
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        $db=mysql_select_db("jobs");
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $arr=explode(".", $image);
        $arr_image=$arr[0].rand();
        $image=$arr_image.".".$arr[1];
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $mname=$_POST['mname'];
        $sname=$_POST['sname'];
        $country=$_POST['country'];
        $city=$_POST['city'];
        $add=$_POST['add'];
        $mob=$_POST['mob'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $website=$_POST['website'];
        $bio=$_POST['bio'];
        $jobt=$_POST['jobt'];
        $dfrom=$_POST['dfrom'];
        $dto=$_POST['dto'];
        $sd=$_POST['sd'];
        $schooln=$_POST['schooln'];
        $degree=$_POST['degree'];
        $shortd=$_POST['shortd'];
        $cv = $_FILES['cv']['name'];
        $file_tmp1 =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $file_tmp2 =$_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp1,"uploads/".$image); 
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp2,"uploads/".$cv); 



        $sql="INSERT INTO  `jobs`.`resume` (`id` ,`image` ,`fname` ,`mname` ,`sname` ,`country` ,`city` ,`add` ,`mob` ,`email`
,`website` ,`bio` ,`jobt` ,`dfrom` ,`dto` ,`sd` ,`schooln` ,`degree`
,`shortd` ,`cv`)
        VALUES ( '$image','$fname',  '$mname',  '$sname', '$country', '$city',  '$add',  '$mob',  '$email',  '$website', 
'$bio',  '$jobt',  '$dfrom',  '$dto',  '$sd',  '$schooln', 
'$degree',  '$shortd','$cv') ";




        //include('candidates.php');
        //print_r($sql); die;
        if ($sql) {



        mysql_query($sql);
        echo" resume uploaded successfully";
        mysql_close($con);
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Check for errors. Write `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())`.

Comment: mysql_*  is outdated use mysqli_* or PDo

Comment: echo $sql; before query execute and copy paste it directly into mysql databse and run it that query  .

Comment: id column is auto_increment ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what is the error

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result)
{
   echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 i get this error .

Comment: The fields you are inserting does not match with the fields in the table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

`issue is` :
       your given id column in field list but not give value for that  id column.

id column is auto_increment mean .
remove `id` column name like this

```
        $sql="INSERT INTO  `jobs`.`resume` (`image` ,`fname` ,`mname` ,`sname` ,`country` ,`city` ,`add` ,`mob` ,`email`
    ,`website` ,`bio` ,`jobt` ,`dfrom` ,`dto` ,`sd` ,`schooln` ,`degree`
    ,`shortd` ,`cv`)
            VALUES ( '$image','$fname',  '$mname',  '$sname', '$country', '$city',  '$add',  '$mob',  '$email',  '$website', 
    '$bio',  '$jobt',  '$dfrom',  '$dto',  '$sd',  '$schooln', 
    '$degree',  '$shortd','$cv') ";
```